# ASP.NET Core + Heroku. Database migration

Tags: database, heroku, asp.net-core, migration

I want to update database on Heroku using migration in ASP.NET Core.
I used correct connection string (DATABASE_URL), but when I run command
`update-database`
from Package Manager Console, I get message
`Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.`

I'll leave my connection string format here:
`postgres://odb...:5670...@ec2-54-243-54-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/2d...`

Answer (score 6):

I thought that `DATABASE_URL` format is good, but it's not, you need to use `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`,
PLUS in the end I passed two additional parameters: `Sslmode=Require;` and `Trust Server Certificate=true`.